# 0 pages crawled(at 0 pages/min) , when running (scrapy+frontera) example

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, frontera

I had made a ([scrapy](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html)+[frontera](https://github.com/scrapinghub/frontera/blob/master/docs/source/topics/frontier-at-a-glance.rst)) example of crawling a single web page.After I entered the command **scrapy crawl myProject** , I am getting this as output -

```
E:\scrapyProject\mirchi>scrapy crawl dmoz
2015-08-17 22:12:54 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.3 started (bot: mirchi)
2015-08-17 22:12:54 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2015-08-17 22:12:54 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'mirchi.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['mirchi.spiders'], 'SCHEDULER': 'frontera.contrib.scrapy.scheduler
s.frontier.FronteraScheduler', 'BOT_NAME': 'mirchi'}
2015-08-17 22:12:58 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
2015-08-17 22:13:04 [py.warnings] WARNING: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\frontera\contrib\scrapy\schedulers\frontier.py:3: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Module `scrapy.log` has been de
precated, Scrapy now relies on the builtin Python library for logging. Read the updated logging entry in the documentation to learn more.
  from scrapy import log

2015-08-17 22:13:06 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, Me
taRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats, SchedulerDownloaderMiddleware
2015-08-17 22:13:06 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware, SchedulerSpiderMiddl
eware
2015-08-17 22:13:06 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
2015-08-17 22:13:06 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2015-08-17 22:13:06 [py.warnings] WARNING: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\frontera\contrib\scrapy\schedulers\frontier.py:123: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: log.msg has been deprecated,
create a python logger and log through it instead
  log.msg('Starting frontier', log.INFO)

2015-08-17 22:13:06 [scrapy] INFO: Starting frontier
2015-08-17 22:13:06 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-08-17 22:13:06 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2015-08-17 22:13:06 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2015-08-17 22:13:06 [py.warnings] WARNING: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\frontera\contrib\scrapy\schedulers\frontier.py:128: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: log.msg has been deprecated,
create a python logger and log through it instead
  log.msg('Finishing frontier (%s)' % reason, log.INFO)

2015-08-17 22:13:06 [scrapy] INFO: Finishing frontier (finished)
2015-08-17 22:13:06 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 17, 16, 43, 6, 848000),
 'frontera/iterations': 0,
 'frontera/pending_requests_count': 0,
 'frontera/seeds_count': 1,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 9,
 'log_count/WARNING': 3,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 17, 16, 43, 6, 681000)}
2015-08-17 22:13:06 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

If I run the above code only on scrapy, its working fine. But after combining both the output says - 0 pages scrawled.What I am doing wrong, please mention in comments if some more info is required.

**Edit** - code of **mirchi\mirchi\settings.py** ->

```
BOT_NAME = 'mirchi'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['mirchi.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'mirchi.spiders'


SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'frontera.contrib.scrapy.middlewares.schedulers.SchedulerSpiderMiddleware': 1000,
}

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'frontera.contrib.scrapy.middlewares.schedulers.SchedulerDownloaderMiddleware': 1000,
}

SCHEDULER = 'frontera.contrib.scrapy.schedulers.frontier.FronteraScheduler'

FRONTERA_SETTINGS = 'frontera.settings'
```

code of **mirchi\mirchi\frontera\settings.py** ->

```
BACKEND = 'frontera.contrib.backends.memory.heapq.BFS'
```

Comment: Can you edit your post and add the `settings.py` contents to it?

Comment: @GHajba done with edits.

Comment: When I look at the documentation of frontera I would define the settings like this: `FRONTERA_SETTINGS = 'mirchi.frontera.settings'`.

Comment: @GHajba - If I do that, console is showing  No module named frontera.settings ..

Comment: OK, how is your directory structure then? It should be organized like described here: https://github.com/scrapinghub/frontera/blob/master/docs/source/topics/scrapy-integration.rst#organizing-files

Comment: @GHajba its same, as shown there. :(

Comment: @GHajba Done, with that.. when I changed the Url that I want to crawl, it worked for the first time.. may be,, it does,'t allowed to duplicate content in backend. Thankyou so much for your efforts..